# What is wrong with my answers?

Tags: support, answers

I keep getting downvotes on my answers and people leave no reasons. I'm thinking it's some malicious person continually doing so, what exactly is wrong with my answers? For instance this:
[How do I change this line of code from R to MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275428/how-do-i-change-this-line-of-code-from-r-to-matlab/54275525#54275525)

User downvoted, no reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the post to which you linked had exactly *one* downvote when you wrote this. One downvote could be based on just about anything; it's really hard to say. It's also not worth worrying about very much.

That said, I suspect you got a downvote because:

- It's not really clear what your answer is. The core of the question was:

  > what is the [1] doing and what is the 0 doing?

  But your answer doesn't mention the `[1]` at all and gives a somewhat ambiguous answer about the `0`.
- This language is confusing and seems to be irrelevant to the answer:

  > Take this with a grain of salt. You can proceed with MATLAB conversion, MATLAB taught me pain.
- It's not immediately clear what your code block at the end is intended to demonstrate.

I am not an R or Matlab expert, but, frankly, I found your answer hard to follow. The other (accepted) answer to the same question was clear enough that I understood it. That contrast could explain why your answer is not performing as well.

I hope this helps. Again, though, a single downvote could be based on almost anything. I would not lose sleep over it.

P.S. Users do not have to explain downvotes and usually will not do so. A comment asking for an explanation 20+ hours after you posted the answer is unlikely to result in much insight.

Comment: Thanks. The comment was placed almost after the downvote was placed. As for the confusing part, I had initially just placed a comment but decided to turn it into an answer. The pain part was intended to be humor(I realize I failed). I will try to make my answers more clear going forward. Thanks again!